# Algorithms - Graph Depth-First Search

Tags: algorithm, topological-sort

I'm learning about graph and DFS, and trying to do something similar to how ANT resolves the dependency. I'm confused about something and all the articles I read seems to assume everyone knows this.

I'm thinking of having a Map> with key = file, and value = set of files that the key depends on.

The DFS algorithm shows that I have to change the color of the node if it's already visited, that means the reference to the same fileNode must be the same between the one in key and the one in Set<> right?

Therefore, I'm thinking, each time a Node is created (including neighbor nodes), I would add it to one more Collection (maybe another Map?), then whenever a new Node is to be add to the graph (as key), search that Collection and use that reference instead? am I wasting too much space? How is it usually done? is there some other better way?

Answer (score 0):

During my studies the DFS algorithm was implement like this:

Put all the nodes of a graph into a stack (this is a structure, where you can only retrieve and delete the first element).

Retrieve the first element, set it to seen, this can either be done through the coloring or by setting an attribute, lets call it isSeen, to true.

You then look at all the neighbors of that node, and if they are not seen already, you put them in the stack.

Once you looked at all the neighbors, you remove the node from the stack and retrieve the next element of the stack and do the same as for the first.

The result will then be, that all the nodes, that can be reached from the starting node, will have an attribute that is set to seen.

Hope this helped.

Comment: "You then look at all the neighbors of that node, and if they are not seen already, you put them in the stack."
This is my problem right here. While you're building the graph, how do you reference the neighbor so that once it's changed color once, its color will be changed everywhere. I.E: Node A could be neighbor of B, C, and D at the same time. So stack could have [B, A, E, C], now we have node A again, but if this node isn't the same reference as the first A, then its color will be white.

Comment: You don't use the DFS algorithm to "build" a graph, you use it on an existing graph. I'm not quite sure what your problem is but let me put it this way. Lets say you are currently looking at a node, then the neighbors are all the node that have an incident with the outgoing edges (or arcs). When you change the color of a node, you don't change the color by reference, but by value. what this means is that you change the color attribute of the neighboring node. So if you would visit it again, the color is still changed. In what language are you implementing this?

Comment: I didn't say I'm building graph with DFS, I'm saying how do I build the graph so that it doesn't conflict with the DFS. I use java. My Node is going to be an instance with : filename, color. My graph is going to be Map<Node, Set<Node> neighbors>. If I make new Node for the same node but different neighbors, then changing the color doesn't work. I guess I can just implement an extra Map to hold all the nodes that has already been added, and do a check every time.

Comment: If you are using java, then make a class for `Node` and include a attribute `isSeen` which is Boolean and an attribute `neighbours`, which is a colection or linkedList of nodes. Make some getter and setter for these attributes and change isSeen to true, if the node is visited in the DFS. Before running DFS, you will need to set the neighbours ofcourse and all the `isSeen` to false.

Comment: Sorry, I could not explain very well. I know how DFS and OOP, what I'm confused about is this part right here: https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/graph/linked/  start at "2 points should be made: In the above edge that goes to B for example, since we don't want to replicate all the information stored about B in this edge node, that reference to B should really be a pointer to the vertex node with B, as in:"

Comment: Its basically what I said before, this is about the neighbors of a give node. Instead of saving all the information about the neighbors in the node itself, you will just point to the neighbor. What they call `EdgeNode` is just a pointer to a neighboring `VertixNode`. `EdgeNode` is basically your arc which has a beginning node and an end node. I don't know how to explain this any better...